# Component's state is derived from its prop and that prop comes from a async API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I encountered this situation recently when developing some business logic. Here is a simplified and contrived example from it

```js
function App() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMyState((prevState) =>
        prevState.concat([
          {
            type: 'foo',
            enabled: true,
          },
          {
            type: 'bar',
            enabled: true,
          },
          {
            type: 'baz',
            enabled: true,
          },
        ])
      )
    }, 500)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChildComponent propFromApp={myState} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

I used `setTimeout` to mock the API call and it passed the state to `ChildComponent`.

```js
function ChildComponent({ propFromApp }) {
  const allTypes = propFromApp.map((item) => item.type)
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState(allTypes)

  return (
    <div>
      {allTypes.map((type, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={type}
            checked={checkedItems.includes(type)}
            onChange={() => {
              if (checkedItems.includes(type)) {
                setCheckedItems((prevState) =>
                  prevState.filter((prevType) => type !== prevType)
                )
              } else {
                setCheckedItems((prevState) => prevState.concat(type))
              }
            }}
          />
          <label htmlFor={type}>{type}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And `ChildComponent` is responsible for rendering a bunch of checkbox based the prop. It first derived an array of `type` from the prop, which is called `allTypes` and then set its own state `checkedItems` using this `allTypes` as the initial value. so initially all of the items are checked. The reason I make `ChildComponent` hold these as its own state is that the component can thus control them via the checkbox.

However because the `propFromApp` is an empty array initially, so `ChildComponent`'s state `checkedItems` is initialized as an empty array as well and would NOT get updated when
the real data comes back from the API call, which is 500ms later when the callback in `setTimeout` is fired.

So then I use `useEffect` to update the `checkedItems` when the prop updates.

so now `ChildComponent` looks like this

```js
function ChildComponent({ propFromApp }) {
  const allTypes = propFromApp.map((item) => item.type)
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState(allTypes)

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckedItems(allTypes)
  }, [allTypes])

  return (....)
```

However this gave an error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
> setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a
> dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I figured it is because `allTypes` is not one of primitive types so the equality checking would always determine that `allTypes` is different every time the component re-renders. So finally I have to change it to using `useMemo` to avoid the problem. Now `ChildComponent` looks like this

```js
function ChildComponent({ propFromApp }) {
  const allTypes = useMemo(() => propFromApp.map((item) => item.type), [
    propFromApp,
  ])
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState(allTypes)

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckedItems(allTypes)
  }, [allTypes])

  return (....)
```

Now it solves the problem. but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it or it is a good practice. Can anyone propose a better alternative or point out where my code is not good enough?

Here is the live dome https://codesandbox.io/s/async-sky-3vl1r?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` in this context usually solves the problem but may not. `useMemo` may or may not recalculate its value based on some memory management logic written by folks smarter than me. Therefore you'll need to write your code keeping in mind the referential identity of the memoized value may change. The referential identity changing means deps arrays will change.

It's fine to use `useMemo` to fix an infinite loop. In most cases a recalculation causes an extra rerender and nothing else.

It's not fine to have `useMemo` affect application logic. In your example a recalculation will reset `checkedItems` while not recalculating does not. To fix the issue, defer deriving values until you need the derivative.

```
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState(() => propFromApp.map((item) => item.type))

  useEffect(() => {
    const allTypes = propFromApp.map((item) => item.type)
    setCheckedItems(allTypes)
  }, [propFromApp])
```

Alternatively, if you have a lot of deps it may get unreasonably onerous to manage deps so closely. You can then explicitly circuit-break the effect callback unless the change you expect has happened.

```
  const prevPropFromApp = useRef(propFromApp)
  const propFromAppChanged = prevPropFromApp.current !== (prevPropFromApp.current = propFromApp)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!propFromAppChanged) return;
    setCheckedItems(allTypes)
  }, [allTypes, propFromAppChanged])
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I actually thought about your first solution but it requires to write `propFromApp.map((item) => item.type` logic twice. I am not sure if I understand what you meant by "it is not fine to use useMemo to change application logic.". Did you mean that in my case I changed the application logic with `useMemo`? Also could you provide an example of changing the application logic with `useMemo`?

Comment: As long as the transformation you need is pure, like the mapping in your example you can just write a helper function for it to avoid duplication. I was indeed unclear in my wording, I'll edit the answer. What I meant to say is it's not fine for the `useMemo` recalculating, or not recalcuting having any difference in terms of application logic. In your example it does make a difference (resetting vs not resetting) and therefore it's not okay and causes bugs.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion but I would skip the useMemo and simply set an If statement around both your useEffects. This makes sure that the useEffect only updates when your conditions are valid.

Example in App:

```
useEffect(() => {

  if(!myState) {
    setTimeout(() => {...
```

Example in Child:

```
useEffect(() => {

    if(!checkedItems && allTypes) {
      setCheckedItems(allTypes)
    }
  }, [allTypes, checkedItems])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I don't think your solution is correct here. `checkedItems` is an array and `! checkedItems` will always return `false`.